# Flutter: How can I stop the bottom nav bar from appearing on user tap?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm making a game and I would like to **see the devices top UI** (time, wifi...) but **hide the bottom nav bar**. The code below hides the bottom nav bar but it appears whenever the user taps on the screen. But, I want the bottom nav bar to ALWAYS be hidden. Thank you for your help.

```
class myApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([SystemUiOverlay.top]);
    return MaterialApp( ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([])
```

Comment: This hides the top UI, which I don't want. I'm using a SafeArea with an AppBar and I want the user to be able to see the time and all the other info at the top.

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround I found so far is to use the [**flutter_statusbar_manager**](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_statusbar_manager) package and call

```dart
FlutterStatusbarManager.setFullscreen(true);
FlutterStatusbarManager.setHidden(false);
```

However, on android the status bar is displayed over the black spot at the top, I'm guessing that it's caused by this [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14432#issuecomment-440275231) (`setFullscreen()` is calling the `SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([])`), so I couldn't find a way to modify its color.